# Replacing the first row to NA and Pushing down one row in R

Tags: r

How can I push one step down or one row down to my data and replacing the first row of the third column to NA and removing the last row of the third column using r?

I want the following data:

```
x   y   z
1   2    3
4   5    6
7   8    9 

to

x   y    z
1   2   NA
4   5    3
7   8    6
```

the code:

```
ave(data, data$z, FUN = function(x) c(diff(x), NA)
```

, gives me the difference, not the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
 transform(df, z = c(NA, head(z, -1)))
  x y  z
1 1 2 NA
2 4 5  3
3 7 8  6
```

You could also do:

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate(df, z = lag(z))
```

Comment: I will appreciate if you hint me how to use this in multiple time series using function or something else? like using the Z value to be NA in the next data.